# What is the relationship between complex time singularities and UV fixed points?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, renormalization, complex-numbers, singularities, turbulence

In [this](http://pra.aps.org/abstract/PRA/v23/i5/p2673_1) paper it is described how the turbulent kinetic energy spectrum and the [flatness](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59788/2751) (a measure for intermittency) are governed by the position of the (dominant) singularities of the solutions of the dynamic equations in the complex plane, as an approach to explain intermittency for example.

An alternative approach to investigate the UV behavior of a turbulent system is to analyze the renormalization group flow field and look at the UV fixed point(s). A possible reason for intermittency from this point of view could be the presence of more than one UV fixed point, as alluded to for example in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.0461) paper about renormalization group analysis of turbulent hydrodynamics.

My question now is: What is the relationship between complex time singularities of the  solutions of the equations of motion describing a turbulent system and the UV fixed point(s) of the renormalization group flow of the same system, if  any? How can these two approaches to investigate the UV behaviour of a turbulent system be brought together?

Comment: Cross-posted to http://mathoverflow.net/q/134939/13917